# Gmail inbox view action doesn't shown

Tags: gmail, google-schemas

I'm trying to add View Action to my emails. For tests I'm send email from grif@ecwid.com to grif@ecwid.com

Example

```
Return-Path: <grif@ecwid.com>
Received: from 172.17.10.84 ([87.251.133.106])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPSA id bj7sm8223219lbc.22.2014.06.06.01.11.43
        for <grif@ecwid.com>
        (version=TLSv1 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA bits=128/128);
        Fri, 06 Jun 2014 01:11:44 -0700 (PDT)
Date: Fri, 06 Jun 2014 01:11:44 -0700 (PDT)
From: grif@ecwid.com
To: grif@ecwid.com
Message-ID: <1817181170.17.1402042304376.JavaMail.rinatgainullin@Rinats-MacBook-Pro-2.local>
Subject: =?UTF-8?B?0JTQvtCx0YDQviDQv9C+0LbQsNC70L7QstCw0YLRjCDQsiBFY3dpZCE=?=
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; 
    boundary="----=_Part_15_1197020028.1402042304374"

------=_Part_15_1197020028.1402042304374
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

....
------=_Part_15_1197020028.1402042304374
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.=
w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns=3D"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv=3D"Content-Type" content=3D"text/html; charset=3DU=
TF-8">
        <title>=D0=94=D0=BE=D0=B1=D1=80=D0=BE =D0=BF=D0=BE=D0=B6=D0=B0=D0=
=BB=D0=BE=D0=B2=D0=B0=D1=82=D1=8C =D0=B2 Ecwid!</title>
=09=09
    <style type=3D"text/css">
.....
</style></head>
    <body leftmargin=3D"0" marginwidth=3D"0" topmargin=3D"0" marginheight=
=3D"0" offset=3D"0" style=3D"margin: 0;padding: 0;background-color: #ffffff=
;">
....
<div itemscope itemtype=3D"http://schema.org/EmailMessage">
=09<div itemprop=3D"action" itemscope itemtype=3D"http://schema.org/ViewAct=
ion">
=09=09<link itemprop=3D"url" href=3D"https://my.grif.ecwid.com:8443/cp/vali=
date?h=3D123&ownerid=3D0"/>
=09=09<meta itemprop=3D"name" content=3D"=D0=9F=D0=BE=D0=B4=D1=82=D0=B2=D0=
=B5=D1=80=D0=B4=D0=B8=D1=82=D1=8C e-mail"/>
=09</div>
</div>
....
    </body>
</html>
------=_Part_15_1197020028.1402042304374--
```

But my inbox letter looks like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAcs7.png
What I should to do to test my schema? Is this feature testing has any restriction?

### Update

When I send mail for myself there are no dkim headers, but when my friend send me mail from his acc dkim header is present

No dkim

```
Return-Path: <grif@ecwid.com>
Received: from test-gmail-actions-0.gen.ec.ecwid.com (ec2-174-129-131-52.compute-1.amazonaws.com. [174.129.131.52])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPSA id s2sm10439008qaj.36.2014.06.26.02.45.56
        for <grif@ecwid.com>
        (version=TLSv1 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA bits=128/128);
        Thu, 26 Jun 2014 02:45:56 -0700 (PDT)
Date: Thu, 26 Jun 2014 02:45:56 -0700 (PDT)
From: Ecwid <grif@ecwid.com>
To: grif@ecwid.com
Message-ID: <22158846.2.1403775956083.JavaMail.root@test-gmail-actions-0>
Subject: =?UTF-8?B?0JTQvtCx0YDQviDQv9C+0LbQsNC70L7QstCw0YLRjCDQsiBFY3dpZCE=?=
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
```

Dkim is present

```
Delivered-To: grif@ecwid.com
Received: by 10.229.14.202 with SMTP id h10csp5187qca; Thu, 26 Jun 2014 03:00:03 -0700 (PDT)
X-Received: by 10.140.96.38 with SMTP id j35mr18742954qge.5.1403776803018;Thu, 26 Jun 2014 03:00:03 -0700 (PDT)
Return-Path: <bender@ecwid.com>
Received: from mail-qa0-x22a.google.com (mail-qa0-x22a.google.com [2607:f8b0:400d:c00::22a])
 by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id e8si8539327qgf.40.2014.06.26.03.00.02
 for <grif@ecwid.com>
 (version=TLSv1 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA bits=128/128);
 Thu, 26 Jun 2014 03:00:03 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of bender@ecwid.com designates 2607:f8b0:400d:c00::22a as permitted sender) client-ip=2607:f8b0:400d:c00::22a;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
 spf=pass (google.com: domain of bender@ecwid.com designates 2607:f8b0:400d:c00::22a as permitted sender) smtp.mail=bender@ecwid.com;
  dkim=pass header.i=@ecwid.com
Received: by mail-qa0-f42.google.com with SMTP id dc16so2614502qab. 
 for <grif@ecwid.com>; Thu, 26 Jun 2014 03:00:02 -0700 (PDT)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;d=ecwid.com; s=google;
....
X-Google-DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
....
```

Answer (score 0):

The email must be signed with DKIM/SPF, I don't see any of the relevant headers in your example.

Comment: Copy message below
@Claudio, https://developers.google.com/gmail/actions/testing-your-schema indicates that you can send to yourself without the need for registration. Is that incorrect?

Comment: It is correct that you don't need registration, but you still need your emails to be signed with DKIM/SPF to prevent spoofing.

Comment: Configure our app to set dkim. But no result yet add update to post